# Detect if two rotated divs collide using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I would like to detect if two rotated divs are colliding. I know how to do it if they're not rotated, but I don't know how to do it when they actually are.

I have tried some collision plugins such as jQuery Collision (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/), but they have not worked when the div is rotated.

I have made the rotation of the divs using CSS's transform property.

Comment: Why not use something like Famo.us to handle physics? I believe they only currently support circular collisions, but https://github.com/DrClick/FamousBird uses rectangular collisions. Check out the source, Luke.

Comment: FamousBird only does rectangle-circle intersection. Since you'll probably have to implement this by yourself, you'll find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/115520/1166087) very helpful. All you need is some addition and multiplication.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://shin.cl/pixelperfect/

Comment: Some previous answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377/javascript-collision-detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not 100% accurate but it does work for most cases, I used the algorythm from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414951/1449710):

```
function isUndefined(a) {
    return a === undefined;
}

/**
 * Helper function to determine whether there is an intersection between the two polygons described
 * by the lists of vertices. Uses the Separating Axis Theorem
 *
 * @param a an array of connected points [{x:, y:}, {x:, y:},...] that form a closed polygon
 * @param b an array of connected points [{x:, y:}, {x:, y:},...] that form a closed polygon
 * @return true if there is any intersection between the 2 polygons, false otherwise
 */
function doPolygonsIntersect (a, b) {
    var polygons = [a, b];
    var minA, maxA, projected, i, i1, j, minB, maxB;

    for (i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {

        // for each polygon, look at each edge of the polygon, and determine if it separates
        // the two shapes
        var polygon = polygons[i];
        for (i1 = 0; i1 < polygon.length; i1++) {

            // grab 2 vertices to create an edge
            var i2 = (i1 + 1) % polygon.length;
            var p1 = polygon[i1];
            var p2 = polygon[i2];

            // find the line perpendicular to this edge
            var normal = { x: p2.y - p1.y, y: p1.x - p2.x };

            minA = maxA = undefined;
            // for each vertex in the first shape, project it onto the line perpendicular to the edge
            // and keep track of the min and max of these values
            for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                projected = normal.x * a[j].x + normal.y * a[j].y;
                if (isUndefined(minA) || projected < minA) {
                    minA = projected;
                }
                if (isUndefined(maxA) || projected > maxA) {
                    maxA = projected;
                }
            }

            // for each vertex in the second shape, project it onto the line perpendicular to the edge
            // and keep track of the min and max of these values
            minB = maxB = undefined;
            for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                projected = normal.x * b[j].x + normal.y * b[j].y;
                if (isUndefined(minB) || projected < minB) {
                    minB = projected;
                }
                if (isUndefined(maxB) || projected > maxB) {
                    maxB = projected;
                }
            }

            // if there is no overlap between the projects, the edge we are looking at separates the two
            // polygons, and we know there is no overlap
            if (maxA < minB || maxB < minA) {
                console.log("polygons don't intersect!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};

$('#r').click(function() {
    var rota = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 ),
        rotb = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 ),
        pointsa = new Array(4),
        pointsb = new Array(4);

    $('#a').css('transform', 'rotateZ(' + rota + 'deg)');
    $('#b').css('transform', 'rotateZ(' + rotb + 'deg)');

    $('#a div').each(function(i) {
        pointsa[i] = {x: parseInt($(this).offset().left), y: parseInt($(this).offset().top)};
    });

    $('#b div').each(function(i) {
        pointsb[i] = {x: parseInt($(this).offset().left), y: parseInt($(this).offset().top)};
    });


    $('#s').val("intersection: " + doPolygonsIntersect(pointsb, pointsa).toString());
});
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VXXP/6/)**

It's not the best way of doing it I guess, what my script does is basically give a random rotation between 0 and 100 degrees, get the x and y positions of each corner (using divs, you can do that with math, also (i cant :D)) and run the algorythm using those coordinates.

Comment: Yeah the separating axis theorem is the way to go. Though you have to get the edges of the rotated boxes. In order to do that it's unavoidable to do dirty math for getting the current rotation angle parsed from css and re-calculating the points of the div (as I don't think there's a more easy way to get the position of the edges). This might help for re-translating and parsing the rotation: http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

I have found [overlaps.js](https://github.com/yckart/jquery.overlaps.js) by **yckart.**

I have made a fiddle with the rotated divs here:  http://jsfiddle.net/n3M5e/

You can change the rotation of the divs in the CSS yourself, and the detection still works well.

**overlaps.js**:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.overlaps = function (obj) {
        var elems = {
            targets: [],
            hits: []
        };
        this.each(function () {
            var bounds = $(this).offset();
            bounds.right = bounds.left + $(this).outerWidth();
            bounds.bottom = bounds.top + $(this).outerHeight();

            var compare = $(obj).offset();
            compare.right = compare.left + $(obj).outerWidth();
            compare.bottom = compare.top + $(obj).outerHeight();

            if (!(compare.right < bounds.left || compare.left > bounds.right || compare.bottom < bounds.top || compare.top > bounds.bottom)) {
                elems.targets.push(this);
                elems.hits.push(obj);
            }
        });

        return elems;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Hope I have helped.

EDIT:

Thanks to @jbrosi, overlaps.js doesn't really work very well with rotated divs.

Comment: It does not really work on rotated boxes - I changed the starting conditions for your fiddle to create a "false position": http://jsfiddle.net/jbrosi/D7vfd/

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for div collision detection.

If you want to raise an event, you have to repeatedly test, but it would be be better just to run the function over all your divs.

The sample demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/nGRwt/7/

Here is the function you need to use

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
      var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
      var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
      var b1 = y1 + h1;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
      var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
      var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
      var b2 = y2 + h2;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;

      if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
    }
```

**Another Demo**

You can also refer to http://jsfiddle.net/98sAG/ for collison detection.

For this use below code :

```
var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions( elem ) {
        var pos, width, height;
        pos = $( elem ).position();
        width = $( elem ).width();
        height = $( elem ).height();
        return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] ];
    }

    function comparePositions( p1, p2 ) {
        var r1, r2;
        r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }

    return function ( a, b ) {
        var pos1 = getPositions( a ),
            pos2 = getPositions( b );
        return comparePositions( pos1[0], pos2[0] ) && comparePositions( pos1[1], pos2[1] );
    };
})();
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: It may be because the OP asked for collision detection when two divs are rotated and yours are not - i didn't downvote btw

Comment: But it doesn't means that it is wrong or not appropriate :(

Comment: Well he did say that he already knew how to do collision detection for non-rotated elements. The question is about rotating/rotated elements.

Comment: OKie, no probs. Got it :)