# How can i set up a collision with a rotated shape in SFML/C++

Tags: c++, sfml

i have a little problem. For the collision in SFML, i use the `intersects()` function.

But this works with a rectangle. How do you block the character with a triangle, or a rotated shape like the one on this screenshot ?

[image]

Comment: I think you should be able to deduct the answer from answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check intersection between 2 rotated rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles)

Comment: SFML is a multimedia library, it's most usable for input and output. For collision detection it's probably better to use physics library (like Box2D).

Answer (score 0):

I am for this problem using `PixelPerfectCollision(sf::Sprite &object1, sf::Sprite object&2)` from `Collison` namespace which i found on [github-sfml collision](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-Simple-Collision-Detection-for-SFML-2). I usually make new `Collision.h` and `Collision.cpp` to my project directory.