# Maintain high precision of the collision checking of two rotated rectangles - SAT collision

Tags: collision, pascal, rectangles, lazarus, freepascal

I implemented SAT to check for collisions of 2 rotated rectangles. Everything works fine, but I noticed that as the objects move, the collision check loses precision.

I set the speed of the squares by (v * 5) * dt.
I determined 5 is one meter in my simulation.

At some point, a collision is detected at that position of the objects:

[image]

Can you advise me on how to keep the high precision of collision checking? Somewhere I found information that multisampling can help. Can you explain to me what it is, how does it solve the precision loss problem and how to implement it?

I wrote my solution in fpc (pascal / lazarus) but it probably doesn't matter. Below is the code:

Creating rectangle corners:

```
rectangle[0].x := position.x-15;
rectangle[0].y := position.y-35;
rectangle[1].x := position.x+15;
rectangle[1].y := position.y-35;
rectangle[2].x := position.x+15;
rectangle[2].y := position.y+26;
rectangle[3].x := position.x-15;
rectangle[3].y := position.y+26;
```

Rotate rectangle:

```
for i:= 0 to 3 do
begin
tempX := rectangle[i].x - position.x;
tempY := rectangle[i].y - position.y;

// now apply rotation
rotatedX := tempX * cos(DegToRad(ang)) - tempY * sin(DegToRad(ang));
rotatedY := tempX * sin(DegToRad(ang)) + tempY * cos(DegToRad(ang));

tempRectangle[i].x := position.x + rotatedX;
tempRetangle[i].y := position.y + rotatedY;

end;

rotatedRectangle:=tempRectangle;
```

And collision checking. This is solution from this post: [How to check intersection between 2 rotated rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962379/how-to-check-intersection-between-2-rotated-rectangles/25261708)
ported to pascal:

Types

```
TRectangle = array[0..3] of TMyPoint;

TMyPoint = record
x:real;
y:real;
end;
```

Collision checking:

```
res:=true; 

for i := 0 to 1 do //2 cars
begin

    // for each polygon, look at each edge of the polygon, and determine if it separates
    // the two shapes
polygon := polygons[i];

    for i1 := 0 to Length(polygon)-1 do
    begin

        // grab 2 vertices to create an edge
        i2 := (i1 + 1) mod 4;
        p11 := polygon[i1];
        p22 := polygon[i2];

        // find the line perpendicular to this edge
        normal.x := p22.y - p11.y;
        normal.y := p11.x - p22.x;

        minA.assigned := false;
        maxA.assigned := false;
        // for each vertex in the first shape, project it onto the line perpendicular to the edge
        // and keep track of the min and max of these values
        for j := 0 to 3 do 
        begin
            projected := normal.x * rectangleA[j].x + normal.y * rectanglA[j].y;
            if ((minA.assigned = false) or (projected < minA.value)) then
                begin
                     minA.value := projected;
                     minA.assigned:=true;;
                end;
            if ((maxA.assigned = false) or (projected > maxA.value)) then
                begin
                     maxA.value := projected;
                     maxA.assigned := true;
                end;
        end;

        // for each vertex in the second shape, project it onto the line perpendicular to the edge
        // and keep track of the min and max of these values
        minB.assigned:=false;
        maxB.assigned:=false;
        for j := 0 to 3 do  
        begin
            projected := normal.x * rectanglB[j].x + normal.y * rectanglB[j].y;
            if ((minB.assigned = false) or (projected < minB.value)) then
                begin
                     minB.value := projected;
                     minB.assigned :=true;
                end;
            if ((maxB.assigned=false) or (projected > maxB.value)) then
                begin
                     maxB.value := projected;
                     maxB.assigned:=true;
                end;
        end;

        // if there is no overlap between the projects, the edge we are looking at separates the two
        // polygons, and we know there is no overlap
        if ((maxA.value < minB.value) or (maxB.value < minA.value)) then
            begin
                              res := false;

            end;
    end;
    end;

   result := res;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be about precision. Did you check, if your polygons (vertices) are specified in either clockwise or counterclockwise order?

Comment: I'll check it out, good lead, thanks

Comment: @divanov42 It looks like everything is ok with this

Comment: Is this "res := false;" equivalent to this "return false"? In the question you referenced, the code returns from the function immediately, when the condition is met, in yours however it seems like it keeps going, and the returned result is whatever res is equal to in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Before first loop I set res:=true;. I forgot to copy this to topic. Anyway I check this one more time.

Comment: @divanov42 I think it cant be problem because I set result true only at start. So even when loop keeps going once result set false it will set to the end.

Comment: Is going away from SAT an option? I am fairly certain, that the problem is in implementation, and not precision - in the image your reactangles are far enough - precision problems will surface only if these two would be almost indistinguishable. Can't you just find if two unrotated rects intersect? Btw. SAT algorithm is only needed if you need to work w. arbitrary convex polygons, in your case task can be greatly simplified. If you choose to go w. SAT, then probably you should review the code from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection.

Comment: @divanov42 I don't insist on the SAT. But will checking unrotated rectangles work, for example, when turning? Thank you, I'll check this link

Comment: If you take two rectangles then simultaneously rotate them about the same point, the distance between them wouldn't change. For pretty much the same reason rotated rectangles will still be rectangles, with the same side lengths.

Comment: I rotate each rectangle around its own center, but maybe this is just fine. I will check, thanks

Comment: I found also this: http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/poly-poly.php
I'll try to implement this and check if this is better.

Comment: @divanov42 You were right, I probably had a bug in the implementation.
I rewrote to pascal the code from the link above and it works much better :) Check collisions correctly :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could help) Good luck with your project)